# @ModelAttribute annotation not able to populate bean variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My controller is annotated as

```
public ModelAndView execute(final HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute final UploadFormBean uploadFormBean) {
    //some code.
    Type t = uploadFormBean.getType();  //t is null.
    //some more code.
}
```

The `UploadFormBean` is defined as:

```
public class UploadFormBean {

    private Type type;

    public enum Type {
        A ("abc"),

        B ("xyz"),

        C ("pqr");

        private final String str;

        private Type(final String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return str;
        }
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(final String type) {
        for (Type s: Type.values()) {
            if (s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                this.type = s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is `@mMdelAttribute` not able to set `type` variable (`t` is null in `execute` function)?

What am I missing? Also, please explain how does `@ModelAttribute` binds the data members from http request to a java bean.

Note: this works fine in case when `type` is a `String` and setType is defined as:

```
void setType(final String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="abc">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="xyz">
```

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617099/spring-3-0-mvc-binding-enums-case-sensitive) helps

Comment: how looks your jsp/html? I think it's `null` because spring can not bind it because spring doesn't know this property.

Comment: @ManuZi I am also guessing that spring is not able to bind it, but then since it was private member spring must be setting it with help of setter. I have kept the setter same in both cases(when type is enum and when it is string). Not sure if spring uses reflection.

Comment: i image that you need something like this in your jsp/html `type.str`

Comment: @ManuZi caould you elaborate more on this.

Comment: before i can do that i need to see your jsp/html. you must have something like that to 'connect' your controller model with the client: `<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{login}" th:placeholder="#{login.name}" />` (that's thymeleaf syntax)

Comment: @ManuZi added JSP component as well.

Comment: i'm wondering that 'submitType' would be worked. i think your setType method is wrong, have you try to remove this method? it would be better we use the so chat option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70419/discussion-between-aman-deep-gautam-and-manu-zi).

Answer (score 0):

1)Why is @mMdelAttribute not able to set type variable (t is null in execute function)?

Because for binding it will expect a setter like like one below.

```
public void setType(final Type type) {
  this.type = type) ;
}
```

But this wont work as path value in spring form,because enum will not have
public constructor.

So better way to achieve this is to re factor your bean like one below

```
public class UploadFormBean {

    private String type;

     public enum Type {
            A ("abc"),

            B ("xyz"),

            C ("pqr");

            private final String str;

            private Type(final String str) {
                this.str = str;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return str;
            }
        }



    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        for (Type s: Type.values()) {
            if (s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                this.type = s.name();
            }
        }

    }
}
```