# Spring Boot bind @Value to Enum case insensitive

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, spring-properties

**Enum**

```
public enum Property {
    A,
    AB,
    ABC;
}
```

**Field**

```
@Value("${custom.property}")
protected Property property;
```

**application.properties** (lower case)

```
custom.property=abc
```

When I'm running application I have an error:

> Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [com.xxx.Property]: no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found.

Whereas (upper case):

```
custom.property=ABC
```

Works fine.

Is there a way to bind the value case insensitive? Like *ABC*, *Abc*, *AbC*, *abc* any pattern should work.

NOTE: I saw this question - [Spring 3.0 MVC binding Enums Case Sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617099/spring-3-0-mvc-binding-enums-case-sensitive) but in my case I have over 10 enums/values (and expect to have more) classes and to implement 10 different custom property binders would be painful, I need some generic solution.

Comment: Looks like a potential bug with relaxed binding.

Comment: Sorry, edited description. Value's case switched.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` features do not match. I couldn't stress enough how `@ConfigurationProperties` is superior.

First, you get to design your configuration in a simple POJO that you can inject wherever you want (rather than having expressions in annotation that you can easily break with a typo). Second, the meta-data support means that you can *very easily* [get auto-completion in your IDE for your own keys](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor).

And finally, the relaxed binding described in the doc only applies to `@ConfigurationProperties`. `@Value` is a Spring Framework feature and is unaware of relaxed binding. We [intend to make that more clear in the doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4892).

TL;DR `abc` works with `@ConfigurationProperties` but won't with `@Value`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephane Nicoll What is the recommendation for Spring 4.?

Comment: @Stephane Nicoll
I thought the relaxed binding has to do with the key. I'm not sure where it is made clear that enum names in the value part will be mapped case-insensitively. It is pretty convenient though.

Answer (score 8):

A problem with ConfigurationPropertis (afaik) is that you cannot use constructor injection, and your class has to be mutable.

A workaround (or hack if you like) would be to use SpEL to uppercase the property before looking it up, like this:

`@Value("#{'${custom.property}'.toUpperCase()}") Property property`

This should work since enums instances are constants, and should always be defined in uppercase: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 2):

Another option is setter injection:

```
protected Property property;

@Autowired
public void setProperty(@Value("${custom.property}") String propertyString) {
  this.property = Property.valueOf(propertyString.toUpperCase())
}
```

It is more verbose than SpEL but it allows you to do more complicated processing

---

You could also combine SpEL with a custom parsing function:

```
package com.example.enums

public enum Property {
  A,
  AB,
  ABC;

  public static Property parse(String name) {
    // you can do more complicated processing here
    return valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
  }

}
```

```
@Value("#( T(com.example.enums.Property).parse('${custom.property}') )")
protected Property property;
```

Answer (score -14):

In a practical world, this works....

```
public enum Property {
    A, a
    AB, ab,
    ABC, abc,
    ABCD, abcd,
    ABCDE, abcde; 

    public boolean isA() {
        return this.equals(A) || this.equals(a);
    }

    public boolean isAB() {
        return this.equals(AB) || this.equals(ab);
    }

    ...etc...

}
```

..although this does break the principle of the enum!