# How to auto convert string values from properties files to other data types i.e. duration using spring conversion service?

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion

How to auto convert string values from properties files to other data types i.e. duration using spring conversion service?

properties file

```
my.duration=PT10M
```

configuration class

```
@Value("{my.duration}")
//It'll give string value by default but I want to convert to duration
private Duration myDuration;
```

How can I achieve that using spring `ConversionService`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot bind @Value to Enum case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565758/spring-boot-bind-value-to-enum-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use YAML, if you want to populate a class with the values from resource files.

Duration.yaml

```
duration:
    val1: "PT"
    val2: "10"
    val3: "M"
```

Duration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "duration")
public class Duration {
    private String val1;
    private String val2;
    private String val3;

    // setters and getters.
}
```

You can play around with this approach to get the desired output.