# Spring Boot convert Enum ignoring case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application which is exposing a [Rest API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT1tp.png). This API accepts a list of enums `batchStatus` as query parameter. This `batchStatus` is to be used to filter all the batches based on their status.

When trying to invoke this rest api, I'm getting the following error

```
{
  "timestamp": 1552587376808,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam @javax.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam com.netshell.test.spring.conversion.rest.api.model.BatchStatus] for value 'active'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.netshell.test.spring.conversion.rest.api.model.BatchStatus.active",
  "path": "/batch/status"
}
```

Spring is looking for **active** in BatchStatus instead of **ACTIVE**.

Looking deep into the spring ConversionService I've discovered two converters
1. StringToEnumConverterFactory (from spring-core)
2. StringToEnumIgnoringCaseConverterFactory (from spring-boot)

Is there any mechanism in spring-boot to force use of second converter?

Further debugging showed that both the converters are registered with ConversionService,  however there are [multiple instances of conversionService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya6zY.png) each with different number of converters. In this case how does spring select which conversionService to use?

Enum `BatchStatus` is created as following

```
public enum BatchStatus {
    ACTIVE("active"),
    FAILED("failed"),
    HOLD("hold");

    private String value;
    BatchStatus(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static BatchStatus fromValue(String text) {
        for (BatchStatus b : BatchStatus.values()) {
            if (String.valueOf(b.value).equals(text)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the issue tracker of the Spring project you can find [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3021) issue, which basically asks for the `StringToEnumIgnoringCaseConverterFactory` class to be made public.
However it seems it won't happen anytime soon, as [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15019) is still in progress.

What you could try is configuring that `Converter` via `WebMvcConfigurer#addFormatters`

```
@Configuration
class CustomWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
        ApplicationConversionService.configure(registry);
    }
}
```

`ApplicationConversionService#configure` will register `StringToEnumIgnoringCaseConverterFactory` for you, by calling the `addApplicationConverters` method

```
/** Spring Framework code */
public static void addApplicationConverters(ConverterRegistry registry) {
    ...
    registry.addConverterFactory(new StringToEnumIgnoringCaseConverterFactory());
}
```

And btw, that's the only reference to `StringToEnumIgnoringCaseConverterFactory`, so it's your only hope ; ) (don't use `Reflection`! Resist the urge)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also as suggested in [one of the comments](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15019#issuecomment-435865413) it is better to create ones own converter instead of using `StringToEnumIgnoringCaseConverterFactory`

Comment: @Abhishek I would not go down that route. Stick to the standard one if it works, for the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Setting **spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums=true** in properties, would solve this

Comment: This is not true. The exception is raised by the method `org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService#convert`, I don't think it has anything to do with the `spring.jackson` package and it's configuration.